# How does one split a column title into two lines?

Tags: tables, rotating

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage{array} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5mm}
\begin{tabular}[h]{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}||>      {\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}|} 
\hline
\rotatebox{90} {\centering case1}      & \rotatebox{90}{\centering Case2}   &  \rotatebox{90}{\centering This is the case 3?} & \rotatebox{90} {\centering Case 4}  \\ \hline\hline
a      &  b    & c  & d  \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\caption{My table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

How can I split the title "This is the case 3" into two lines?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: A MWE should start with `\documentclass` and call all the packages necessary to compile it.

Comment: Does this help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40465/line-break-in-rotatebox-in-table

Comment: Downvote: You are not a newbie here and should know to include an MWE.

Comment: but i have the packages that i have used , that's it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to use something like

```
\parbox{2cm}{\raggedright This is the case 3?}
```

or add a `\\` to manually split the line:

```
\parbox{2cm}{\raggedright This is \\ the case 3?}
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5mm}
\begin{tabular}[h]{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}||>      {\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}|} 
\hline
\rotatebox{90} {\centering case1}      & \rotatebox{90}{\centering Case2}   &  
\rotatebox{90}{\centering \parbox{2cm}{\raggedright This is the case 3?}} & \rotatebox{90} {\centering Case 4}  \\ \hline\hline
a      &  b    & c  & d  \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}[h]{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}||>      {\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}|} 
\hline
\rotatebox{90} {\centering case1}      & \rotatebox{90}{\centering Case2}   &  
\rotatebox{90}{\centering \parbox{2cm}{\raggedright This is \\ the case 3?}} & \rotatebox{90} {\centering Case 4}  \\ \hline\hline
a      &  b    & c  & d  \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you mean \rotatebox{90}\parbox{2cm}{\centering \raggedright This is the case 3?}  ? it didn't work ;(

Comment: Can you first complete your code snippet in the question so that I can cut and paste and get it to compile.  That way I can be sure I am using the same packages as you.

Comment: \rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2cm}{ This is \\ the case 3?}} it works :)

Comment: thank you for answer, please i have one more question: how can i divide a line in a cellule ? simple cellule not the title.

Comment: @researcher: If I understand you correctly you could either use the `p{}` column type, as in the example here in which case it should already wrap. Or, use a `\parbox{<length>}{}` for the content.  If that does not work, then you should post a separate question as it is not related to the title of this question.  And as I am not quite the expert as some other people here, so I would have to actually see the table and try things to find the ideal solution.

Comment: i have added \newline between words and it works :)

Answer (score 4):

The `\centering` in

```
 \rotatebox{90}{\centering This is the case 3?}
```

is doing nothing, it is like

```
 \mbox{\centering This is the case 3?}
```

In both cases there is a single TeX horizontal (LR) box in which no linebreaking happens.

Depending on the appearance that you want any of the following work and give different effects

---

```
\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2cm}{\centering This is the\\ case 3?}}
```

---

```
\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2cm}{This is the\\ case 3?}}
```

---

```
\rotatebox{90}{This is the}
\rotatebox{90}{case 3?}}
```

---