# Create table using Latex

Tags: tables

I'm a beginner in LaTeX formatting text software.

Can somone help me create this table using LaTeX:

[image: latex table]

Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\renewcommand\tablename{Tableau~2.2}
\caption{\textbf{Valeurs typiques des paramètres d'un moteur à courant continu.}}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c||c|c||c|c|} 
\hline
&\multirow{3}{*}{Paramètre}&  \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Valeur typique}\\
\hline
&~&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Puissance $P_{m} (kW)$}\\
\cline{2-5}
\hline
&~&5&25&100&500\\
\hline
Moteur&N(tr/min)&1800&1800&1800&18000 \\
&V(V) &240&440&440&1800 \\
&$R_{a} (m \Omega)$&615&430&71&14\\
&$L_{a} (mH)$&4,5&5,5&1,8&0,19\\
&$K_{m} (V.s)$&1,2&2,0&2,1&3,0\\
&$\tau_{f} (kW)$&100&250&400&520\\
&$P_{fm} (KW)$&0,35&1,1,1&1,8&5,2\\
&$J_{m}(kg.m^{2}$&0,05&0,2&0,83&10,3\\
&$\tau_{a}(ms)$&7&13&25&14\\
&$\tau_{m}(ms)$&21&22&13&16\\
&$\eta(\%)$&80&85&91&94\\
\hline
Entraînement&$R_{a} (m \Omega)$&1230&860&142&28\\
&$L_{a} (mH)$&4,9&6,0&2,0&0,21\\
&$J_{m}(kg.m^{2}$&0,30&1,2&5,0&62\\
&$\tau_{a}(ms)$&4,1&7,0&14,1&7,5\\
&$\tau_{m}(ms)$&250&258&156&192\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show the code you tried so far?

Comment: i post it thanks for your help

Comment: question is edited can somone help to answer thaanks

Comment: You're mostly done.  What aspects are you missing?  I see that you have `\hline` overwriting `\cline`.  Other than that, it looks like you're just needing to rotate the boxes, and you can try some ideas from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40465/107497.  Or is there something else that you're missing?

Comment: the problem is that when i rotate the text it gives spaces in other colum lines

Comment: also i need to delete lines from the empty cells and from the cells where i have( paramètre )

Comment: Please don't use `[H]` for floats as the float is then no longer a float. `\[htbp]` is much better.

Comment: Okey sir thank you for you help

Answer (score 5):

Welcome on TeX.SX! There you go (sorry for the little joke):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating, multirow}

\begin{document}

\rotatebox{-2}{%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|r|r|r|r|} 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{} & \multirow{3}{*}{Paramètre} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Valeur typique}\\
\cline{3-6}
& &\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Puissance $P_{m}$ (kW)}\\
\cline{3-6}
& & 5 & 25 & 100 & 500\\
\hline
\multirow{11}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Moteur}} & $N$ (tr/min) & 1800 & 1800 & 1800 & 18000 \\
& $V$ (V) & 240 & 440 & 440 & 1800 \\
& $R_{a}$ (m$\Omega$) & 615 & 430 & 71 & 14 \\
& $L_{a}$ (mH) & 4,5 & 5,5 & 1,8 & 0,19 \\
& $K_{m}$ (V $\cdot$ s) & 1,2 & 2,0 & 2,1 & 3,0 \\
& $\tau_{f}$ (kW) & 100 & 250 & 400 & 520 \\
& $P_{fm}$ (KW) & 0,35 & 1,1 & 1,8 & 5,2 \\
& $J_{m}$ (kg $\cdot$ m\textsuperscript{2}) & 0,05 & 0,2 & 0,83 & 10,3 \\
& $\tau_{a}$ (ms) & 7 & 13 & 25 & 14 \\
& $\tau_{m}$ (ms) & 21 & 22 & 13 & 16 \\
& $\eta$ (\%) & 80 & 85 & 91 & 94 \\
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Entraînement}} & $R_{a}$ (m$\Omega$) & 1230 & 860 & 142 & 28 \\
& $L_{a}$ (mH) & 4,9 & 6,0 & 2,0 & 0,21 \\
& $J_{m}$ (kg $\cdot$ m\textsuperscript{2}) & 0,30 & 1,2 & 5,0 & 62 \\
& $\tau_{a}$ (ms) & 4,1 & 7,0 & 14,1 & 7,5 \\
& $\tau_{m}$ (ms) & 250 & 258 & 156 & 192 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To make everything fit, I suggest you increase the row spacing a bit using `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}`.

Comment: You're cruel :D

Comment: Now thats customer focus .... love it.

Comment: Thaanks a loot you are a lifesaver

Comment: @MrFlutter You just need to remove the outer `\rotatebox` of course.

Comment: You missed the gap in the last vertical line.:-)

Answer (score 4):

My understanding of the usual recommendations is that it's far easier to scan similar values down than across.  Consequently, I would recommend transposing your table.  For example, now I see how each of the parameters changes with $P_m$ and that Entraînement is repeating 5 of the parameters (although I'm not quite sure about the translation, so you may need to separate Entraînement into a separate table).  I've also incorporated the package booktabs, which allows for slightly different thicknesses of the rules.  You may also want to consider the package siunitx which can automatically align your numbers on the `,` instead of needing to pad them with trailing zeros (and can make typing the units a bit easier).  In my quick attempt, however, siunitx made the table too wide (and it's already a bit too wide with the default settings).

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Valeurs typiques des paramètres d'un moteur à courant continu pour une puissance donnée ($P_m$).}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ r r r r r r r r r r r r } 
\toprule
$P_m$ & $N$ & $V$ & $R_a$ & $L_a$ & $K_m$ & $\tau_f$ & $P_{fm}$ & $J_m$ & $\tau_a$ & $\tau_m$ & $\eta$ \\
kW & tr/min & V & m$\Omega$ & mH & V$\cdot$s & kW & kW & kg$\cdot$m\textsuperscript2 & ms & ms & \% \\
\midrule
5 & 1800 & 240 & 615 & 4,50 & 1,2 & 100 & 0,35 & 0,05 & 7,0 & 21 & 80 \\
25 & 1800 & 440 & 430 & 5,50 & 2,0 & 250 & 1,10 & 0,20 & 13,0 & 22 & 85 \\
100 & 1800 & 440 & 71 & 1,80 & 2,1 & 400 & 1,80 & 0,83 & 25,0 & 13 & 91 \\
500 & 18000 & 1800 & 14 & 0,19 & 3,0 & 520 & 5,20 & 10,30 & 14,0 & 16 & 94 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{12}{c}{Entraînement}\\
\midrule
5 &&& 1230 & 4,90 &&&& 0,30 & 4,1 & 250 \\
25 &&& 860 & 6,00 &&&& 1,20 & 7,0 & 258 \\
100 &&& 142 & 2,00 &&&& 5,00 & 14,1 & 156 \\
500 &&& 28 & 0,21 &&&& 62,00 & 7,5 & 192\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: code output]

Comment: Thanks dude for your help