# How to make table with rotated table headers in LaTeX

Tags: tables, color, rotating

I saw a table created in PowerPoint and wanted to know how to do it in LaTeX. The table is shown below. The aspects of the table that I'm most interested in are the rotated table headers as well as `Knowledge Areas` and `Process` labels outside the table.

[image: screenshot]

Here is what I've come up with so far after seeing [Rotated column titles in tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32683/rotated-column-titles-in-tabular)
 suggested in the comments (thanks!)

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcolumntype{R}[2]{%
    >{\adjustbox{angle=#1,lap=\width-(#2)}\bgroup}%
    l%
    <{\egroup}%
}
\newcommand*\rot{\multicolumn{1}{R{90}{1em}}}% no optional argument here, please!

\begin{document}

\begin{table} \centering
    \begin{tabular}{clcccccccccc}
        & & \multicolumn{10}{c}{Knowledge Areas} \\
        & & \rot{Integration} & \rot{Scope} & \rot{Time} & \rot{Cost} 
        & \rot{Quality} & \rot{Human Resource} & \rot{Communication} 
        & \rot{Risk} & \rot{Procurement} & \rot{Stakeholder Management} \\
        \midrule
        \multirow{5}{*}{{Processes}}
        & Initiating             & * &   &   &   &   &   & * &   &   & * \\
        & Planning               & * & * & * & * & * & * & * & * & * & * \\
        & Executing              & * &   &   &   & * & * & * &   & * & * \\
        & Monitoring and Control & * & * & * & * & * &   & * & * & * & * \\
        & Closing                & * &   &   &   &   &   & * &   & * & * \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Some caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

With the result looking like:

[image]

I'm not so concerned about the row coloring (sorry, should have mentioned that before). There are just a few things I don't know how to do:

1. How can I make `Stakeholder Management` stack on top of each other?
2. How can I rotate `Processes` on the left-hand side? The `\rot` command I used in the table header didn't work, presumably because it is in the `\multirow` command.

Comment: could you show what you've tried so far? perhaps [Rotated Column Titles in Tabular](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32683) will get you started....

Comment: Did you searched for suitable similar questions? Rowcoloring and rotating should be already covered.

Comment: those labels "Knowledge Areas" and "Process" are not really labels, there are just a further row and a further column, respectively. can be done with multirow and multicolumn. And this table has a flaw that I would not want to copy. Stuff should be readable when the head is tilted to the left. Like the process lable. All the stuf in the green part is the wrong way round.

Comment: @eject I tried to make the `Process` label on the left side rotated 90º like the table headers, but got an error. Do you know how to make it work?

Comment: I tried using your code and I kept getting unrecognized command errors (so I presume it does not survive entering an `\input`), so I substituted it directly in the table (a longtable, in fact). Like this:
`\multicolumn{1}{>{\adjustbox{angle=90,lap=\width-(1em)}\bgroup}<{\egroup}}{\textbf{Header1}}&`
And this yields:
`! Package array Error: <{..} at wrong position: changed to !{..}.`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Using `\rlap` makes it easier to position text without additional space. And if you want the label "Processes" outside then use `\cmidrule{2-12}` and `\cmidrule[1pt]{2-12}` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\newcommand*\OK{\ding{51}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{} cl*{10}c @{}}
        & & \multicolumn{10}{c}{Knowledge Areas} \\[2ex]
        & & \rot{Integration} & \rot{Scope} & \rot{Time} & \rot{Cost} 
        & \rot{Quality} & \rot{Human Resource} & \rot{Communication} 
        & \rot{Risk} & \rot{Procurement} & \rot{\shortstack[l]{Stakeholder\\Management}} \\
        \cmidrule{2-12}
        & Initiating             & \OK &   &   &   &   &   & \OK &   &   & \OK \\
        & Planning               & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK \\
        & Executing              & \OK &   &   &   & \OK & \OK & \OK &   & \OK & \OK \\
        & Monitoring and Control & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK &   & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK \\
 \rot{\rlap{~Processes}}
        & Closing                & \OK &   &   &   &   &   & \OK &   & \OK & \OK \\
        \cmidrule[1pt]{2-12}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Some caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

and the same colored:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\newcommand*\OK{\ding{51}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} \centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} cr*{10}c }
   & & \multicolumn{10}{c}{Knowledge Areas} \\[2ex]
\rowcolor{blue!30} \cellcolor{white}
   & & \rot{Integration} & \rot{Scope} & \rot{Time} & \rot{Cost} 
   & \rot{Quality} & \rot{Human Resource~} & \rot{Communication} 
   & \rot{Risk} & \rot{Procurement} & \rot{\shortstack[l]{Stakeholder\\Management}} \\
        \cmidrule{2-12}
\rowcolor{black!15} \cellcolor{white}
   & Initiating   &\OK &    &    &    &    &    &\OK &    &    &\OK \\
   & Planning     &\OK &\OK &\OK &\OK &\OK &\OK &\OK &\OK &\OK &\OK \\
\rowcolor{black!15} \cellcolor{white}
   & Executing    &\OK &    &    &    &\OK &\OK &\OK &    &\OK &\OK \\
   & Monitoring and Control 
                  &\OK &\OK &\OK &\OK &\OK &    &\OK &\OK &\OK &\OK \\
\rowcolor{black!15} \cellcolor{white}
 \rot{\rlap{~Processes}}
   & Closing      &\OK &    &    &    &    &    &\OK &    &\OK &\OK \\
        \cmidrule[1pt]{2-12}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Some caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You didn't use `pstricks`?

Comment: Very nicely done.

Comment: I’d use `\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-12}` for the bottom line to have the same width as `\bottomrule`.

Comment: Too bad the color version has an option clash for `xcolor` when using beamer.

Comment: @ago: write _before_   `\documentclass`  the command `\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}` or pass the option `table` via `beamer` to `xcolor`.

Answer (score 29):

When I tried to read your table, I found it impossible to read the column headings because of the rotation, which is why I recommend a solution without rotation. All it is is a simple reorganisation of the rows and columns.

It isn't perfect. Perhaps aligning the *Processes* to the right is better.

You can simplify the table as well because all knowledge areas require planning, so why put it in the table? Just mention it in the caption. Removing the column for planning should make the table less wide, which is always a good thing because it makes it easier to scan the table from left to right and back.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand*\ON[0]{$\surd$}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lccccc@{}}
           & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Processes}}
    \\  \cmidrule{2-6}
           & & & & \textbf{Monitoring}
    \\       \textbf{Knowledge Areas}
           & \textbf{Initiating}
           & \textbf{Planning}
           & \textbf{Executing}
           & \textbf{\&\ Control}
           & \textbf{Costing}
    \\ \midrule
       \textbf{Integration}    & \ON & \ON & \ON & \ON & \ON
    \\ \textbf{Scope}          &     & \ON &     & \ON &
    \\ \textbf{Time}           &     & \ON &     & \ON &
    \\ \textbf{Cost}           &     & \ON &     & \ON &
    \\ \textbf{Quality}        &     & \ON & \ON & \ON &
    \\ \textbf{Human Resource} &     & \ON & \ON &     &
    \\ \textbf{Communication}  & \ON & \ON & \ON & \ON & \ON
    \\ \textbf{Risk}           &     & \ON &     & \ON &
    \\ \textbf{Procurement}    &     & \ON & \ON & \ON & \ON
    \\ \textbf{Stakeholder
               Management}     & \ON & \ON & \ON & \ON & \ON
    \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Some caption}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Table]

Comment: +1 For not having to turn my head to read anything. To be  personally I would have left out the "Processes", as is self-evident.

Answer (score 26):

I had made a similar table for my use.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside, 10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\mcrot}[4]{\multicolumn{#1}{#2}{\rlap{\rotatebox{#3}{#4}~}}} 

\newcommand*{\twoelementtable}[3][l]%
{%  
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}#1@{}}%
        #2\tabularnewline
        #3%
    \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h] \label{tab:activityTracking}
    \centering
    \caption{Tracking daily activities.}
\begin{tabular}{ *2{ll|} *6c | *6c }
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Date}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Start} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Stop} 
        & \mcrot{1}{l}{60}{Activity 1} & \mcrot{1}{l}{60}{Analysis} & \mcrot{1}{l}{60}{\twoelementtable{No. of}{processes}} & \phantom{p}& \mcrot{1}{l}{60}{Result} & \mcrot{1}{l}{60}{Backup} 
        & \mcrot{1}{l}{60}{Activity 2} & \mcrot{1}{l}{60}{Analysis} & \mcrot{1}{l}{60}{\twoelementtable{No. of}{processes}} & \phantom{p} & \mcrot{1}{l}{60}{Result} & \mcrot{1}{l}{60}{Backup} \\
    \midrule \midrule

    \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{January}}}
    & 11 & 1:30~am & 10:45~am 
        & x & x & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-} & - & x 
        & - & x & \multicolumn{2}{c}{x} & x & x \\
    & 12 &          &         
        & - & - & \multicolumn{2}{c}{x} & - & - 
        & - & - & \multicolumn{2}{c}{x} & - & - \\
    & 13 &          &         
        & - & - & \multicolumn{2}{c}{x} & - & - 
        & - & - & \multicolumn{2}{c}{x} & - & - \\
    & 14 &          &         
        & - & - & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-} & - & - 
        & - & - & \multicolumn{2}{c}{x} & - & - \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply this to rotated cells at the very bottom of the table?

Comment: The only thing I really do not like with your approach is that you have with multiple line boxes a bad alignment of the header!

Answer (score 3):

You can easily create that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 6.22 of 2023-08-14).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{cl*{10}{c}}
        & & \Block{1-10}{Knowledge Areas} \\[1mm]
        \RowStyle{\rotate}
        & &  Integration &  Scope &  Time &  Cost &  Quality &  Human Resource &  Communication 
        &  Risk &  Procurement & \Block{}{Stakeholder \\ Management} \\
        \midrule
        \Block{*-1}{\rotate Processes}
        & Initiating             & * &   &   &   &   &   & * &   &   & * \\
        & Planning               & * & * & * & * & * & * & * & * & * & * \\
        & Executing              & * &   &   &   & * & * & * &   & * & * \\
        & Monitoring and Control & * & * & * & * & * &   & * & * & * & * \\
        & Closing                & * &   &   &   &   &   & * &   & * & * \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \caption{Some caption}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Your NiceTabular rocks!