# How to include skewed text in a table

Tags: tables, rotating, booktabs

I would like to make a table like this one, in which the columns have skewed text (I use booktabs):

[image]

I tried to search everywhere, but couldn't find an answer.
Any advice on this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Thank you, @Mico. Thanks for the extra label!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow diagonal overlapping of the rotated headers, it's best to encase the `\rotatebox` directives in `\rlap` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs,amssymb}
\newcommand\rot[1]{\rlap{\rotatebox{45}{#1}}}
\newcommand\OK{$\checkmark$}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{9pt} % default: 6pt
\centering
     \begin{tabular}{@{} *{7}{l} }
     Reference & \rot{Ownership} 
               & \rot{No Claim Without Burn} 
               & \rot{Doublespend Prevention}
               & \rot{Decentralized Finality}
               & \rot{Transfer Confirmation}
               & \rot{Implementation}\\
     \midrule
     XCLAIM    & \OK & \OK &     & \OK &     & \OK \\
     Metronome & \OK & \OK & \OK &     & \OK & \OK \\
     Gazi      & \OK &     &                       \\
     \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

No code provided so using a sample from this site -- [How to make table with rotated table headers in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98388/how-to-make-table-with-rotated-table-headers-in-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{60}}
\newcommand*\OK{\ding{51}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{} cl*{5}c @{}}
        & & \rot{Integration} & \rot{Scope} & \rot{Time}\\
\midrule
        & Initiating             & \OK &   &   \\
        & Planning               & \OK & \OK & \OK\\
        & Executing              & \OK &   &   \\
        & Monitoring and Control & \OK & \OK &  \\
        & Closing                & \OK &   &  \\
\midrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Some caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is precisely what I need! Thanks a lot!