# Table line is missing at the top right

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{Tool/technique for scope definition}
    %\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
        \label{tab:fir}
        \centering
        \begin{adjustbox}{width=15cm, height=5.0cm}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{3.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{.5cm}|}
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Techniques/tools}} & \multicolumn{6}{>{\centering}p{1\textwidth}}{\textbf{Combination of different approaches used as monitoring and controlling \newline methods in Software Project management}}\\  \cline{2-7}
            &Monitoring & Quantification & Controlling & Visualizing&Completeness & Ref \\

        \hline
        Earn Value Management and Gantt Chart & $1$ & $0$ & $1$&$1$ & $0$ & \cite{sillitti2011agile} \\
        \hline 
    Earn Value Management and statistical Methods & $1$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0$& $0$ & \cite{levin2009fundamentals} \\
        \hline 
    Earn Value Management and Kanban & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ &$1$ & $0$ & \cite{corral2011evolution}\\
        \hline 
        Value Stream Mapping and Kanban & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ &$1$  &$0$ & \cite{hans2013work}\\
        \hline
        Scrum and Kanban & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ &$1$ & $0$ & \cite{wnuk2009feature}  \\

        \hline 
    Control charts & $1$ & $0$ & $1$ &$1$ & $0$ & \cite{sanghera2008fundamentals} \\
        \hline 
    PRINCE 2 and Balance Scored Method& $1$ & $0$ & $0$ &$0$ & $0$ & \cite{sanghera2008fundamentals}  \\
        \hline 
        Cumulative Flow Diagram with some metrics&$1$ & $0$ & $1$&$1$ & $0$ & \cite{sanghera2008fundamentals} \\
        \hline 
    Earn Value Management and critical path method & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ &$1$ & $0$ & \cite{sliger2008software}  \\


        \hline 
    EVM and Use Case Point& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\

        \hline 
    \end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

Table line is missing at the top right corner, plzzz help

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: To fix the issue mentioned in the title of your posting, all you'll have to do is change `\multicolumn{6}{>{\centering}p{1\textwidth}}{...}` to `\multicolumn{6}{>{\centering}p{1\textwidth}|}{...}`. However, as I set forth in my answer, you should re-evaluate your entire approach to designing the table, say, with the help of a `tabularx` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

`\multicolumn{6}{p{13.5cm}|}{\centering\textbf{Combination of different approaches used as monitoring and controlling  methods in Software Project management}}`

would fix the error and add the missing vertical line:

[image]

However, the resulting table looks distorted, due to the use of `adjustbox`. To make the table fit onto the page, I'd suggest the usage of `tabularx`. In order to save space, you could rotate the table column headings as follows. I have also shortened the text in the multirow, as I would try to add the information into the caption of the table. Additionally, I have removed vertical lines and replaced horizontal lines by `booktabs`' rules:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{R}[2]{%
    >{\adjustbox{angle=#1,lap=\width-(#2)}\bgroup}%
    l%
    <{\egroup}%
}
\newcommand*\rot{\multicolumn{1}{R{45}{1em}}}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{Tool/technique for scope definition}

        \label{tab:fir}
        \centering
     \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l*6{Y}}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Techniques/tools}} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Approaches}}
            \\  \cmidrule{2-7}
            &\rot{Monitoring}  & \rot{Quantification} & \rot{Controlling} & \rot{Visualizing} & \rot{Completeness} & \rot{Ref} \\

        \midrule
        Earn Value Management and Gantt Chart & 1 & 0 & 1&1 & 0 & \cite{sillitti2011agile} \\

    Earn Value Management and statistical Methods & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0& 0 & \cite{levin2009fundamentals} \\

    Earn Value Management and Kanban & 1 & 0 & 0 &1 & 0 & \cite{corral2011evolution}\\

        Value Stream Mapping and Kanban & 1 & 0 & 0 &1  &0 & \cite{hans2013work}\\

        Scrum and Kanban & 1 & 0 & 0 &1 & 0 & \cite{wnuk2009feature}  \\


    Control charts & 1 & 0 & 1 &1 & 0 & \cite{sanghera2008fundamentals} \\

    PRINCE 2 and Balance Scored Method& 1 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0 & \cite{sanghera2008fundamentals}  \\

        Cumulative Flow Diagram with some metrics&1 & 0 & 1&1 & 0 & \cite{sanghera2008fundamentals} \\

    Earn Value Management and critical path method & 1 & 1 & 1 &1 & 0 & \cite{sliger2008software}  \\



    EVM and Use Case Point& 1 & 0&  1& 1& 0 & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\

        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The code for the rotated table headers is borrowed from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32690/134144

Comment: +1 for the second solution. Since it looks like you don't want to allow line breaks in the first column, you may want to assign the `l` column type to it, and switch to using a centered version of the `X` column type for the 6 data columns.

Comment: A minor suggestion: Maybe replace `\multicolumn{6}{p{4.5cm+10\tabcolsep}}{\centering\textbf{Approaches}}` with `\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Approaches}}`?

Comment: @Mico: Thanks a lot for your suggestions, that significantly simplify the code. I have incorporated them into my answer.

Comment: Don't forget to drop the surplus `\centering` instruction. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `adjustbox` to make tabular material fit inside the textblock, unless you really wish to risk making the font size so small as to make the material unreadable without a magnifying glass. Instead, load the `tabularx` environment, set its width to `\textwidth` and allow line breaks in the five header cells.

For the following screenshot, I've set the variable `\textwidth` to `15cm` as that's the value you use in your code for the width of the `adjustbox`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[textwidth=15cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}       % default: 6pt
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}  % for a more open "look"

\caption{Tool/technique for scope definition}
\label{tab:fir}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| >{\RaggedRight}p{4cm} | *{5}{C|} c |}
\hline
    Techniques\slash tools & 
    \multicolumn{5}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr5\hsize+8\tabcolsep\relax}C|}%
    {Combination of different approaches used as monitoring 
     and controlling methods in Software Project management} & Ref. \\  
    \cline{2-6}
    & Monitoring  & Quantification & Controlling 
    & Visualizing & Completeness   & \\
    \hline
    Earn Value Management and Gantt Chart 
      & $1$ & $0$ & $1$&$1$ & $0$ & \cite{sillitti2011agile} \\
    \hline 
    Earn Value Management and statistical Methods 
      & $1$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0$& $0$ & \cite{levin2009fundamentals} \\
    \hline 
    Earn Value Management and Kanban 
      & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ &$1$ & $0$ & \cite{corral2011evolution}\\
    \hline 
    Value Stream Mapping and Kanban 
      & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ &$1$  &$0$ 
      & \cite{hans2013work}\\
    \hline
    Scrum and Kanban 
      & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ &$1$ & $0$ 
      & \cite{wnuk2009feature}  \\
    \hline 
    Control charts 
      & $1$ & $0$ & $1$ &$1$ & $0$ 
      & \cite{sanghera2008fundamentals} \\
    \hline 
    PRINCE 2 and Balance Scored Method
      & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ &$0$ & $0$ 
      & \cite{sanghera2008fundamentals}  \\
    \hline 
    Cumulative Flow Diagram with some metrics
      &$1$ & $0$ & $1$ & $1$ & $0$ 
      & \cite{sanghera2008fundamentals} \\
    \hline 
    Earn Value Management and critical path method 
      & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ &$1$ & $0$ 
      & \cite{sliger2008software}  \\
    \hline 
    EVM and Use Case Point
      & $1$ & $0$ & $1$& $1$ & $0$ 
      & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
    \hline 
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: how can i write the headings of 5 multi column fully in the above code? e g. Monitoring, Quantification, controlling, visualizing, completeness .

Comment: @avais - please clarify what you mean by writing the 5 headers "fully". Do you mean "on a single line"?