# Use a legend and references instead of a table header

Tags: tables, header

I'm sure this is a common problem:
Sometimes, the header of a table is way too big for the columns:

You end up with a table that is either too high, too wide or just ugly to look at.

[image]

Previously, I sticked to rotating the table header, but in this case that table is rotated, too. Which means the reader must turn around the page *two* times before being able to understand the table. Rotating the text the other way around would be kind of wrong in a typography sense or at least not best practice.

The table is currently created by the following code:

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{landscape}
  \footnotesize
  \begin{longtable}{ p{2.5cm} p{11cm} l l l p{1cm} l p{1cm} }
    & \textbf{Beschreibung}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  & \rot{\textbf{Beliebtheit\footnotemark}} & \rot{\textbf{Skalierbarkeit}} & \rot{\textbf{Kompatabilität}}  &  \rot{\parbox[t]{4cm}{\textbf{Größe des Ökosystems}\\\textbf{und der Community}}} & \rot{\textbf{Gesamtbewertung}} & \rot{\textbf{Kommerziell}} \\
    \toprule
    \textbf{ElasticSearch\footurl{https://www.elastic.co/de/}}                                         & ElasticSearch ist in Java geschrieben und basiert auf Lucene. Die Suchmaschine ist Teil eines großen Ökosystems, des sogenannten Elastic Stacks. Durch eine große Skalierbarkeit und Flexibilität ist sie auf Enterprise-Applikationen ausgelegt. & 5 &  &  &  &  & nein \\
    \textbf{Solr\footurl{https://lucene.apache.org/solr/}}                                             & Solr ist eine Suchmaschine, die auf Lucene basiert und in Java geschrieben ist. Die Entwickler beschreiben das Tool als \enquote{zuverlässig, skalierbar und fehlertolerant} \cite{ASF2019}.                                                      & 2 &  &  &  &  & nein \\
    \textbf{Splunk\footurl{https://www.splunk.com/de_de}}                                              & Splunk bietet verschiedene Lösungen an, mit denen eine Enterprise Search umgesetzt werden kann, hauptsächlich Splunk Enterprise und Splunk Cloud. Der Entwickler legt Fokus auf eine flexible, anpassbare Lösung \cite{Splunk>2019}.              & 2 &  &  &  &  & ja \\
    \textbf{Amazon CloudSearch\footurl{https://aws.amazon.com/de/cloudsearch/}}                        & Amazon CloudSearch ist ein Cloud-Service, der eine vollumfängliche Suchlösung bereitstellt. Anwender können Daten hochladen aus denen automatische ein Suchindex erstellt wird.                                                                   & 1 &  &  &  &  & ja \\
    \textbf{Google Cloud Search\footurl{https://gsuite.google.com/intl/de/products/cloud-search/}}     & Mit Google Cloud Search können unternehmensinterne Datenquellen durchsuchbar gemacht, die Lösung setzt dabei wie Amazon CloudSearch auf Cloud-Technologie. Der Service löst 2019 Google Search Appliance vollständig ab.                          & - &  &  &  &  & ja \\
    \bottomrule
    \caption{Bewertung wichtiger Suchmaschinen als Entscheidungsgrundlage}
    \label{table:engine-rating}
  \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\footnotetext{Die Beliebtheit wurde einer Statistik von DB-Engines \cite{DBEngines2019} entnommen und auf den Bereich $[1, 5]$ normalisiert.}
```

To rotate the table header, I currently use the code proposed in [this tex SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32690/169956), I just changed it to 90 degrees.

What is the best way to create a table header that just references a legend somewhere else (Header: "A" "B" "C", bottom of the page: A: "Beliebtheit" and so on...)?

Here you can see what I mean (please excuse the bad quality, that's the best I can do at my workplace...):

[image]

Comment: You can use `threeparttable` and write the legend as a table note. Other posssibility: rotate the column heads by only, say, 30°. To avoid having too wide columns in the latter case, you may use the `\rlap` command.

Comment: I have rotated them by only a few degrees, but the table is just too big that way, plus as I said, it's not convenient for the reader, as the table is already inside a `\begin{landscape}`, I will try the `threeparttable`, though

Comment: Did you use  `\rlap` for the column heads?

Comment: No, I do not, i will add my table as a snippet in a moment

Comment: Another possibility is to use \tikzmark to locate the headers and tikz in overlay mode to add the headers, either rotated or offset with arrows.  You might need to add some blank space for the tikzpicture.

Comment: Could you please make your example code compilable? (See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) Also, how are `\rot` and `\footurl` defined?

Comment: Could you please also add, why you used `longtable`? Does your actual table contain more rows so you need the possibility for a pagrebreak within the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion using the `threeparttablex` package in combination with `xltabular`. This is based on the assumption that your actual table will be longer than the one shown in your question so a pagebreak inside of the table will be needed.

[image]

Depending on the contents of the last columns of the table, you could also comment out the `landscape` environment in teh MWE below and obtain teh following table:

[image]

If your table will not be longer than a single age, I'd recommend to use `threeparttable` instead of `threeparttablex` and `tabularx`instead of `xltabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{calc}


\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{url}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{landscape}
  \footnotesize
  \begin{ThreePartTable}
  \begin{TableNotes}
     \item[1] Die Beliebtheit wurde einer Statistik von DB-Engines \cite{DBEngines2019} entnommen und auf den Bereich $[1, 5]$ normalisiert.
     \item[2] \url{https://www.elastic.co/de/}
     \item[3] \url{https://lucene.apache.org/solr/}
     \item[4] \url{https://www.splunk.com/de_de}
     \item[5] \url{https://aws.amazon.com/de/cloudsearch/}
     \item[6] \url{https://gsuite.google.com/intl/de/products/cloud-search/}
  \end{TableNotes}
  \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{ >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm} X l l l l l l }
      \caption{Bewertung wichtiger Suchmaschinen als Entscheidungsgrundlage}\\
      \endhead
      \bottomrule
      \multicolumn{8}{p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{\textbf{A}: Beliebtheit, \textbf{B}: Skalierbarkeit, \textbf{C}: Kompatabilität, \textbf{D}: Größe des Ökosystems und der Community, \textbf{E}: Gesamtbewertung, \textbf{F}: Kommerziell}\\
      \insertTableNotes
      \endfoot
    & \textbf{Beschreibung}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  & \textbf{A\tnote{1}} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C}  &  \textbf{D} & \textbf{E} & \textbf{F} \\
    \toprule
    \textbf{ElasticSearch\tnote{2}}                                         & ElasticSearch ist in Java geschrieben und basiert auf Lucene. Die Suchmaschine ist Teil eines großen Ökosystems, des sogenannten Elastic Stacks. Durch eine große Skalierbarkeit und Flexibilität ist sie auf Enterprise-Applikationen ausgelegt. & 5 &  &  &  &  & nein \\
    \textbf{Solr\tnote{3}}                                             & Solr ist eine Suchmaschine, die auf Lucene basiert und in Java geschrieben ist. Die Entwickler beschreiben das Tool als \enquote{zuverlässig, skalierbar und fehlertolerant} \cite{ASF2019}.                                                      & 2 &  &  &  &  & nein \\
    \textbf{Splunk\tnote{4}}                                              & Splunk bietet verschiedene Lösungen an, mit denen eine Enterprise Search umgesetzt werden kann, hauptsächlich Splunk Enterprise und Splunk Cloud. Der Entwickler legt Fokus auf eine flexible, anpassbare Lösung \cite{Splunk>2019}.              & 2 &  &  &  &  & ja \\
    \textbf{Amazon CloudSearch\tnote{5}}                        & Amazon CloudSearch ist ein Cloud-Service, der eine vollumfängliche Suchlösung bereitstellt. Anwender können Daten hochladen aus denen automatische ein Suchindex erstellt wird.                                                                   & 1 &  &  &  &  & ja \\
    \textbf{Google Cloud Search\tnote{6}}     & Mit Google Cloud Search können unternehmensinterne Datenquellen durchsuchbar gemacht, die Lösung setzt dabei wie Amazon CloudSearch auf Cloud-Technologie. Der Service löst 2019 Google Search Appliance vollständig ab.                          & - &  &  &  &  & ja \\
    \label{table:engine-rating}
  \end{xltabular}
  \end{ThreePartTable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I played around with threeparttable yesterday and came up with a similar solution, I just got hung up on the columns not being references to the notes (I looked into it, because of the formatting this would require a lot more work). This is perfect, though. I will update my questing to add the missing information.