# Multipage tabularx in threeparttable environment

Tags: longtable, tabularx, threeparttable

I have the problem that tables that are larger than one page are not properly split but just overlap the first page.
I use `tabularx` with `ltablex` what works fine on its own but as soon as I wrap the whole thing into a `threeparttable` it doesn't break the page anymore. Is this combination supported? I know I could try `longtable` but I'd prefer to not have to have a special package depending on the size of the table.

Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,notitlepage]{article}   % papersize, fontsize, documentclass; 
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}     % to have a dedicated notes section after tables
\usepackage[font=small, margin=0pt]{caption}            % table and figure captions
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                  % used for table alternatively colors
\usepackage{booktabs}                       % use package booktabs for easy creating tables

% Spacing and margin rules
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}%
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{7pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{5pt}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% CAPTION STYLE
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DeclareCaptionFormat{labelstyle}{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{3pt}%
    \colorbox{blue}{{#1}}#2#3
} 

\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false, labelfont={color=white}}    % Rechtsbündige Tabellen und Bildbeschreibung
\captionsetup[figure]{singlelinecheck=false, labelfont={color=white}, justification = raggedright, format=labelstyle}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% TABLE
\newcommand{\tablestyle} { 
    \captionsetup{type=table, format=labelstyle}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
    \arrayrulecolor{blue} 
    \aboverulesep = 0mm 
    \belowrulesep = 0mm 
    }

\newenvironment{tableenv}[2]{
    \par\vspace{0.5cm}
    \def\tablecaption{#1}
    \def\tablelabel{tab:#2}
        \small
        \tablestyle
        \begin{table}
        \begin{threeparttable}
}{
        \caption{\tablecaption}
        \label{\tablelabel}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section with long table}
\begin{tableenv}{test}{test}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} X @{}}

    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\
\end{xltabular}
\end{tableenv}

\end{document}
```

It's still not breaking the table and I can't figure out why, it does break if I remove the `tableenv` environment tough.

Comment: Probably take a look at `threeparttablex`?

Comment: I just found `threeparttablex` in combination with longtable (for multi page tables), is there a solution for using it with `tabularx` as well?

Comment: I don't know since I prefer `xltabular` over `ltablex` when it comes to multiple page tables with `X` type columns. `xltabular` and `threeparttablex` work well together (See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504666/134144)

Comment: I suggest using the `xltabular` package and its eponymous environment, which loads `ltablex` and automatically adds the `\keepXColumns` automatically; `threeparttablex`  works with xltabular.

Comment: Tried `xltabular` but couldn't get it working inside `threeparttablex` - posted a MWE

Comment: Absolutely not threeparttable for multi-page tables!

Comment: `threeparrtablex` has a different syntax than `threeparttable`. `\begin{ThreePartTable}` vs. `\begin{threeparttable}`. Also, you can't place a tabular that should break across pages into a `table` environment.

Comment: To summarize my aboe comment, the following should work: `\newenvironment{tableenv}[2]{
    \par\vspace{0.5cm}
%    \def\tablecaption{#1}
%    \def\tablelabel{tab:#2}
        \small
        \tablestyle
        %\begin{table}
        \begin{ThreePartTable}
}{
%        \caption{\tablecaption}
%        \label{\tablelabel}
    \end{ThreePartTable}
   % \end{table}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section with long table}
\begin{tableenv}{test}{test}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} X @{}}
\caption{my caption text here}\label{label}\\
    awdafgawfgawfa\\ `

Comment: Works like a charm, unfortunately I don't remember why I've put an additional `table` there in the first place, we'll see when something else stops working :)
Do you wanna post an answer?