# How to make column width adaptive to slanted texts in a table?

Tags: tables, multicolumn, columns, column-width

In the table below, I have tried to make my long texts, in the third row of the table, slanted by Werner's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32683/rotated-column-titles-in-tabular):

```
\documentclass[border = 2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\NewDocumentCommand{\rot}{O{45} O{1em} m}{\makebox[#2][l]{\rotatebox{#1}{#3}}}%

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{6pt}}ccccc@{}}
        \toprule  
        Strategies&\multicolumn{4}{c}{Types}\\
        \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{2-5}    
        &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Type A}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Type B}\\
        \cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{4-5}
        &\rot{A long text here}&\rot{A very very very long text here}&\rot{A very very long text here}&\rot{A very very very very long text here}\\
        \cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{4-5}
        An strategy & 0 &1&2&3\\
        \bottomrule     
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But, column setting do not adapt to the slanted setup leading to the result below:

[image]

Is there an automatic way to adjust the columns based on a slant value?

Comment: The long texts you want to typeset diagonally seem to have a number associated to them, namely 0, 1, 2, 3. Why not typeset the texts in the caption table instead?

Comment: @egreg: There is no such association, and those numbers are just mere fillers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusting the column width to the contents is the default. However, you are hiding the width of the slanted text by putting it in a `\makebox`. So you would have not to use a `\makebox` or give it an adequate optional `width` argument. Like: `\rot[45][\width]{A very very very very long text here}`

```
\documentclass[border = 2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\NewDocumentCommand{\rot}{O{45} O{1em} m}{\makebox[#2][l]{\rotatebox{#1}{#3}}}%

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{6pt}}ccccc@{}}
        \toprule  
        Strategies&\multicolumn{4}{c}{Types}\\
        \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{2-5}    
        &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Type A}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Type B}\\
        \cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{4-5}
        &\rot{A long text here}&\rot{A very very very long text here}&\rot{A very very long text here}&\rot[45][\width]{A very very very very long text here}\\
        \cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{4-5}
        An strategy & 0 &1&2&3\\
        \bottomrule     
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]