# Angled cells and background colors in tabular environment

Tags: tables

I'm trying to make a table where the top row is angled at 45 degrees and has a background fill; there's a few different ways I've found of making angled text in cells, but one thing I can't figure out is how to make background color follow the angle along with the text. I've got code from here: [Rotated column titles in tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32683/rotated-column-titles-in-tabular) which creates the angles I want, but it overrides column color. I can use the `rotating` package to keep the color, but that doesn't angle the cell itself, only the text in it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcolumntype{R}[2]{%
    >{\adjustbox{angle=#1, lap=\width-(#2)}\bgroup}%
    l%
    <{\egroup}%
}
\newcommand*\rot{\multicolumn{1}{R{45}{1em}}}
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{blue!15}}l}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lla}
    & \rot{Column 1}    & \rot{Column 2} \\
\hline
Information & X         & \\
More information    &           & X \\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

I'm assuming I need to insert a column color into the `\newcolumntype` but I'm not sure where it goes with the other code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand exactly what you want, but here is a suggestion with the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\rot}{m}{\rlap{\hspace*{2mm}\rotatebox{45}{#1}}}


\NewDocumentCommand{\ColumnColor}{mm} % #1 : number of column ; #2 ; color
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture} [fill = #2]
    \fill let \p1 = (1) , \p2 = (2) , \n1 = { \y1 - \y2 }
          in (2-|#1) -- ($(2-|#1)+(\n1,\n1)$) 
                     -- ($(2-|\inteval{#1+1})+(\n1,\n1)$) 
                     -- (2-|\inteval{#1+1}) 
                     -- cycle ;
    \fill (2-|#1) rectangle (last-|\inteval{#1+1}) ; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }


\begin{NiceTabular}{lll}
\CodeBefore
  \ColumnColor{2}{red!15}
  \ColumnColor{3}{blue!15}
\Body
                    & \rot{Column 1} & \rot{Column 2} \\
  \Hline
  Information      & X              &                \\
  More information &                & X              \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes used by `nicematrix`).

[image: Output of the above code]

---

If you want to add a color to the first row (excepted for the ``angled cells''), you can't use `\rowcolor` in the `\CodeBefore` for a technical reason: the commands `\rowcolor`, `\cellcolor`, `\columncolor`, etc. don't act in the order of their occurrence in the `\CodeBefore` because they are grouped by color (in order to avoid thin white lines between panels of the same color in some PDF viewers).

Maybe I should add to key to the package `nicematrix` in order to disable that feature for the situations like this one.

With the current version of `nicematrix`, you have to define your own command `\RowColor` which will do the job by using Tikz to fill a rectangle delimited by the PGF/Tikz provided by `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\rot}{m}{\rlap{\hspace*{2mm}\rotatebox{45}{#1}}}


\NewDocumentCommand{\ColumnColor}{mm} % #1 : number of column ; #2 : color
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture} [fill = #2]
    \fill let \p1 = (1) , \p2 = (2) , \n1 = { \y1 - \y2 }
          in (2-|#1) -- ($(2-|#1)+(\n1,\n1)$) 
                     -- ($(2-|\inteval{#1+1})+(\n1,\n1)$) 
                     -- (2-|\inteval{#1+1}) 
                     -- cycle ;
    \fill (2-|#1) rectangle (last-|\inteval{#1+1}) ; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\RowColor}{mm} % #1 number of row ; #2 : color
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture} [fill = #2]
    \fill (#1-|1) rectangle (\inteval{#1+1}-|last) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }


\begin{NiceTabular}{lll}
\CodeBefore
  \RowColor{1}{gray!10}
  \ColumnColor{2}{red!15}
  \ColumnColor{3}{blue!15}
\Body
                    & \rot{Column 1} & \rot{Column 2} \\
  \Hline
  Information      & X              &                \\
  More information &                & X              \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Comment: This did exactly what I need but I'm now running into a secondary issue, where I am trying to color the top row except for those angled cells. I specified ```\rowcolor{}``` but it overrides the column colors; I tried using the Block syntax of nicematrix but it still leaves the white slice before the angled columns. Is there a way to set it up so the column colors override the row color?

Comment: Good question. I have modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect!