# Rotated bold font in NiceTabular table heading

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, rotating, makecell, nicematrix

I am making table using both `nicematrix` and `makecell` packages, because these packages applied together allow to obtain multirow heading cells containing rotated text (as pointed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562752/how-to-make-a-table-with-multirow-rotated-cells); if I am not wrong, `makecell` package alone [enables making cells with rotated text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210869/how-to-align-rotated-column-headings-in-a-table), enables merging vertically adjacent cells, but not both for a single cell).
I need to highlight table-heading content by setting not only gray background, but also bold font. I have two problems/questions:

1. The content of `\Block` is shifted upward from the cell center - letter `Ś` touches top bounding line of the cell (see picture below); and letter `m` in the cell with rotated text almost touches the corresponding bounding line of the cell. How to center `\Block` content automatically?
2. Does the `\Block` command enable for application bold footnotesize font for a group of cells, like `\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}` in `makecell` package?

Code:

```
\documentclass[table]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines,code-before=\rowcolor{gray!30}{1-3}]{%
    S[table-format=2.1]
    S[table-format=1.2]
    S[table-format=2.1]
}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Średnia wartość\\czegoś tam}} & 
{\Block{2-1}{\rotate \makecell{Obrócony opis\\kolumny B}}} \\
{\Block{2-1}{\rotate \makecell{straszne dane}}}
& \rotate \makecell{inne dane\\z długim opisem} \\
& {A} & {B} \\
63.5 & 4.87 & 63.5\\
88.4 & 5.13 & 88.4\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problems are not linked to the command `\Block` (provided by `nicematrix`) since the command `\Block` is *not* used in both cells with problems (however, using `\Block` in those cells won't solve the problems since the command `\Block` does not create space).

In fact, your problems would arise in a standard `{tabular}` of LaTeX (provided you use explicitely `\rotatebox` instead of the syntactic variant `\rotate` provided by `nicematrix`).

---

For the first cell (whose content is `Średnia wartość czegoś tam`), I suggest to use the command `\gape` provided by `makecell` since you have used the command `\makecell`.

That gives : `\gape[t]{\makecell{Średnia wartość\\czegoś tam}}`.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines,code-before=\rowcolor{gray!30}{1-3}]{%
    S[table-format=2.1]
    S[table-format=1.2]
    S[table-format=2.1]
}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\gape[t]{\makecell{Średnia wartość\\czegoś tam}}} & 
{\Block{2-1}<\rotate>{Obrócony opis\\kolumny B}} \\
{\Block{2-1}<\rotate>{straszne dane}}
&{\Block{}<\rotate>{inne dane\\z długim opisem\;}}\\
& {A} & {B} \\
63.5 & 4.87 & 63.5\\
88.4 & 5.13 & 88.4\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you for explanations. I have one more problem: I tried to put `\bfseries` into angle brackets after `\Block` command (I would like to make bold the whole content of the table heading, which is already marked by gray background). But without success. Is the `\Block` argument in angle brackets dedicated only for mathematical mode? How to set font globally for the whole heading, including cells made with `\multicolumn` as well as `\Block` commands?

Comment: As of now, the bracket argument is dedicated for arrays in math mode. Indeed, in `{NiceTabular}`, there is no need to such argument: you may simply put your command `\bfseries` in the main argument of `\Block`: `\Block{2-2}{\bfseries My text}`. In arrays in math mode, it's not possible to put a command such as `\Large` in math mode and that's why I've created the options in angular brackets.

Comment: OK. I don't know, why I didn't find that solution for bold font (before I asked the question): `{\Block{2-1}{\bfseries\rotate \makecell{Obrócony opis\\kolumny B}}}`. It works.

Answer (score 2):

For the `blocks`, the text is already at the center. If you want to shift further, use `\hspace` to achieve the desired output. For the `spacing`, you can try adjusting the cell width else reduce the size of the text, so that the text will not touch the cell border. This can be achieved by using `\small` or `\scriptsize`. Just use it before the text.

```
\documentclass[table]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines,code-before=\rowcolor{gray!30}{1-3}]{%
S[table-format=2.1]
S[table-format=1.2]
S[table-format=2.1]
}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{\scriptsize{Średnia wartość}\\\scriptsize{czegoś tam}}} & 

{\Block{2-1}{\hspace{-.4cm}\rotate \makecell{Obrócony opis\\kolumny B}}} \\
{\Block{2-1}{\centering\rotate \makecell{straszne dane}}}
& \rotate \makecell{inne dane\\z długim opisem} \\
& {A} & {B} \\
63.5 & 4.87 & 63.5\\
88.4 & 5.13 & 88.4\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

Edited answer after comment:

```
\documentclass[table]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines,code-before=\rowcolor{gray!30}{1-3}]{%
S[table-format=2.1]
S[table-format=1.2]
S[table-format=2.1]
}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{\scriptsize{\textbf{Średnia wartość}}\\\scriptsize{\textbf{czegoś tam}}}} & 

{\Block{2-1}{\hspace{-.4cm}\rotate \makecell{\small \textbf{Obrócony opis}\\\small\textbf{kolumny B}}}} \\
{\Block{2-1}{\centering\rotate \makecell{\small \textbf{straszne dane}}}}
& \rotate \makecell{\scriptsize \textbf{inne dane}\\\scriptsize \textbf{z długim opisem}} \\
& {A} & {B} \\
63.5 & 4.87 & 63.5\\
88.4 & 5.13 & 88.4\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the rotated text is aligned to the cell center, why the the height of the cell is not sufficient for symmetrical margins? I don't understand why letter "z" is above the horizontal line and word "opisem" almost touches the horizontal line above it. It is not centered. Do you know how to set bold font for the text in all heading cells (filled with gray)?

Comment: See my recent edit.