# Vertical text - Header Table

Tags: tables, rotating

I'm having problems creating this table in LaTeX:
[image: Table Pretended]

The command `\rotatebox` isn't doing the job in this case. Can someone help me?

My actual situation is:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Nome do Colaborador}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Idade (Anos)}} & \multirow{2}{*}{Antiguidade (Anos)} & \multirow{2}{*}{Função} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Género} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Habilitações}                      \\ \cline{5-11} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                     &                               &                                     &                         & M            & F            & 1º Ciclo & 2º Ciclo & 3º Ciclo & Secundário & Superior \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                     &                               & \multirow{5}{*}{}                   &                         &              &              &          &          &          &            &          \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-11} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                     &                               &                                     &                         &              &              &          &          &          &            &          \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-11} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                     &                               &                                     &                         &              &              &          &          &          &            &          \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-11} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                     &                               &                                     &                         &              &              &          &          &          &            &          \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-11} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                     &                               &                                     &                         &              &              &          &          &          &            &          \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{Total}                                 &                               &                                     &                         &              &              &          &          &          &            &          \\ \cline{2-11} 
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{Média}                                 &                               &                                     &                         &              &              &          &          &          &            &          \\ \cline{2-11} 
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{\%}                                    &                               &                                     &                         &              &              &          &          &          &            &          \\ \cline{2-11} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What have you tried so far?

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14730/big-table-with-rotated-column-labels-using-booktabs

Comment: @DaiBowen ![Image Link](http://imgur.com/a/NPGfj) This is my current situation :|

Comment: Dai Bowen intended what you have done _in LaTeX_ = please add a minimal working example. You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @DaiBowen Thank you for clarifying. Post edited.

Comment: Is [How to make table with rotated table headers in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98388/106162) of use?

Answer (score 8):

This should give you a starting point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} r *{10}{c} @{}}
  \toprule
  & & & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{G\'{e}nero} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Habilita\c{c}\~{o}es} \\
  Nome del Colaborador &
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Idade (anos)} &
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Antiguidade (anos)} &
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Fun\c{c}\~{a}o} &
  M &
  F &
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{1\textsuperscript{o} Ciclo} &
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{2\textsuperscript{o} Ciclo} &
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{3\textsuperscript{o} Ciclo} &
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Secundario} &
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Superior} \\
  \midrule
  \\
  \\
  \\
  \\
  Total & \\
  M\'{e}dia & \\
  \% & \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]